# javafx ComboBox<Integer>'s setValue(Integer) method causes NullpointerException

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a `ComboBox<Integer>` where I want to set an initial selected value to. I also have a `ChangeListener` attached to the selectedItemProperty:

```
this.cbPlayerCount = new ComboBox<>(observableArrayList(2, 3, 4));
cbPlayerCount.getSelectionModel()
             .selectedItemProperty()
             .addListener(this::playerCountChanged);

cbPlayerCount.setValue(2);
```

The call of the `setValue` method triggers a chain of propertyChangeListeners (mine not included) and finally throws a `NullpointerException`.
The signature of my listener method looks like this:

```
private void playerCountChanged(ObservableValue<?> val, int old, int newVal)
```

However the code of it is never invoked. The stacktrace looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel.lambda$new$154(ComboBox.java:494)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(SingleSelectionModel.java:215)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.select(SingleSelectionModel.java:149)
at javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(SingleSelectionModel.java:103)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.lambda$new$152(ComboBox.java:262)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:105)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setValue(ComboBoxBase.java:150)
at de.dk.bm.menu.view.MenuView.<init>(MenuView.java:33)
...
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using a jdk1.8.0_92.
There is no error message or anything, just the Exception. I tried commenting the code that adds the ChangeListener, even though that code is never invoked. Without the listener attached, the Exception doesn't appear. But I still  don't know why it is thrown when the listener is added. I don't want to debug the framework code to look for the mistake that leads to this issue. Why is this Exception thrown? Is it a bug in the javafx framework or did I just use it wrong?

Comment: What does the method `playerCountChanged` look like?

Comment: The methods signature looks like that: "private void playerCountChanged(ObservableValue<?> val, int old, int newVal)", if that was your question. It fits the ChangeListener interface

Comment: You add a change listener, and then you get an NPE when you do something that causes the change listener to fire. You should provide the change listener code, because that *could* be causing your NPE.

Comment: Don't you want `(ObservableValue<? extends Integer>, Integer, Integer)`? If you use 'int' you can get NPE's from casting.

Comment: Nope, if you look at the stacktrace, you will see that the listener code is never executed. The NPE is thrown directly inside the framework code.

Comment: You should make a test case. Also, why cant you provide the code? Or why can't you make another listener, that you can provide the code for that also demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @matt, yes thank you! That was the error! If I use Integer instead of int, the NPE is thrown insinde my playerCountChanged method.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was that I used the `int` type for the parameters of my `playerCountChanged(Observable<?>, int, int)` method.
So the first time a value is selected (by the call of the `setValue` method), there was no previous selected value, so the value passed as the parameter `int old` is `null`. Because I used `int` instead of `Integer` java tries to autobox the `Integer` value into an `int` value, which cannot be done with `null`.
So if I use `Integer` instead, the `NullPointerException` is thrown in my own code where I can fix it.